# More elegant way to define class of DIV, inside DIVs

Tags: html, css

lets see this:

```
<div class="login_container">
  <div>Log in:</div>
  <div>Username:</div>
  <div>Jelszó:</div>
</div>
```

I want the "log in" text have another class. Normally, I would do this:

```
<div class="login_container">
  <div class="textCenter login_container_title">Log in:</div>
  <div>Username:</div>
  <div>Jelszó:</div>
</div>
```

but that would make it a bit complicated. I heard about :first or another magic ( < ) things in CSS, is there a way to do it more elegant?

Comment: It depends on why you want the additional class(es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in CSS with `:first-child` pseudo-element:

```
.login_container > div:first-child {color:#f00}
```

(For `:first-child` to work in IE8 and earlier, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared.)

Or like Lohn Smith does it with jQuery:

```
$('.login_container div:first').addClass('highlight');​
```

A simple [example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2eqK/)

Comment: this looks OK. Is there a way to refert the second, third ... elements?

Comment: "to work in IE8 and earlier, a must be declared" sorry what? This: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">"? Im using HTML 5

Comment: Yes you are right! Just replace `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` with `<!DOCTYPE>`. That is the valide HTML5 doctype...

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to add the class to the first element of the login_container div.

```
jQuery("div#login_container div:first").addClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
.login_container > div:first-child {}
```

this will be more efficient than jQuery